# Managing a collection of libraries for C++ development on Windows

Tags: c++, windows

I'm responsible for developing a set of C++ libraries and programs.  Currently building on Linux and MacOS, but Windows support is also a requirement.  We will need to support VS2010 and VS2012, and in the future will also include VS2013 and maybe also MinGW.  We're using cmake for building, so our code should build on all the platforms without issues; my problem is how to manage all the dependencies on Windows in order to be able to build in the first place, and keeping it up-to-date over time.  At the moment, we have one virtual machine per visual studio version as a jenkins slave, so parallel builds of all the variants is fairly easy, but managing it is not.

The problem is the number of variants this requires building.  If we consider only VS2010 and VS2012, with debug/release and i386/x64 builds, that's already 8 copies of each library; 16 if we include the other compilers.  We will need all the libraries our code depends on, which will include at a minimum boost, qt, xerces+xalan, zlib, icu, libpng/tiff/jpeg, hdf5 and more, plus python, and all their dependencies.  And as new upstream releases are made, we'll need to keep the entire collection up-to-date and consistent for all the build/arch/compiler variants.

I don't want to do this by hand, since this really needs automating.  However, I'm unaware of any good solution for doing this on Windows.  The Windows building guides I've seen for other projects often involve hand-building all the dependencies, and only build for a single variant.  On Linux, it's already packaged, you don't need separate debug builds, and the arch variants can be catered for with chroots; on MacOS there's homebrew, macports etc., and it's also fairly simple to automate stuff there as well.  Is there any equivalent for Windows?  I've looked at stuff like chocolatey, but it's entirely unsuited to handling libraries, and is pretty poor as a package manager.

This seems like it should be a common problem for anyone doing C++ development on Windows?  Are there any common solutions, tools or methodologies for managing a complex set of libraries and tools for development?  How do other developers manage this?

NB.  Just for the record, we are not using the visual studio application; we're doing all builds non-interactively via scripts driving the compilers directly with cmake and/or msbuild.

Many thanks,
Roger

Comment: I have heard of a project named 0install, http://zero-install.sourceforge.net/ but I haven't evaluated it yet.

Comment: Delivering this to external customers would be a nightmare.  For internal customers we require an enterprise wide compiler version, so we only have to update one supported set for upstream changes.

Comment: I have used Nant build before, and it was pretty good at automating the build of several variants of the same code.  There is a link [here](http://iainhunter.wordpress.com/2012/05/11/automating-visual-studio-2010-builds-and-deployments-with-nant-builder/) which gives a brief overview on its usage.  Alternatively perhaps a custom MSBuild script would suffice (link [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84411/customising-your-build-process-with-msbuild/) gives example usage, though you probably already know how to use it by the sounds of it:)

Answer (score 0):

I  worked on large windows C++ project that delivers X86 Release, x86 Debug, x64 Release and x64 debug. Very similarly I used build system that does parallel builds for all target platforms using custom script.

We manage all third party dependency libraries in organized folders.
For example x86\release\Zlib.dll x86\Debug\zlib.dll x64\release\zlib.dll x64\zlib.dll

Custom script is made to pick all these libraries and project source code from configuration management tool. This allows to automatically build the relevant target binaries as needed.

any third party libraries change is updated in configuration management tool and then later picked up by the script for the next build.

For your question on VS2010 and 2012 support I don't understand importance. Is not one version of VS enough to support for the project?

Comment: With regard to support of multiple VS versions, this is because we are providing GPL/BSD sources, not binaries; the end user may wish to use a different compiler.  While we will provide binaries, this is primarily an output of our internal continuous integration rather than something directly intended for end use.

When it comes to managing all the third party dependencies, this is the crux of the issue.  When you say you have an organisation for this and script to build them, that's exactly what I'm looking for.  Is what you're doing here custom, or is there a more standard solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php), and their build system https://github.com/gisinternals/buildsystem

It's basicly a set of batch and make files calling each others. You still need keep track of lib update manually.